# React state value transfer to another state without repeating value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-select

I am using the react-select library for multi-select. I am using it as a state selector but the problem is the react-select an array of objects. Like

```
{
        "label": "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
        "value": "Andaman and Nicobar Islands"
    },
    {
        "label": "Andhra Pradesh",
        "value": "Andhra Pradesh"
    },
```

I want to extract the value part from it and I tried directly but It gave me an error I decided to use a different state array to extract but the problem is I only accept three state values and also want to remove duplicate values new state also have only values. I couldn't fix this problem help me to fix this.

```
const [job_preference, setJobPreference] =
        useState([]);
    const [multiSelect, setMultiSelect] = useState(
        []
    );
```

---

```
const handleMultiSelectChange = (val) => {
        setMultiSelect(val);
    };

const handleJobPreference = () => {
        multiSelect?.map((select) =>
            setJobPreference((prev) => [
                ...prev,
                select.value,
            ])
        );
    };
```

---

```
<div className='mb-3'>
                                    <label className='form-label'>
                                        Job Preference
                                    </label>
                                    <Select
                                        value={multiSelect}
                                        isMulti
                                        components={
                                            animatedComponents
                                        }
                                        isSearchable
                                        placeholder='Choose any 3 states as job location'
                                        options={states}
                                        onChange={
                                            handleMultiSelectChange
                                        }
                                        isOptionDisabled={() =>
                                            multiSelect.length >= 3
                                        }
                                    />
                                </div>
```

Comment: Please show what `handleMultiSelectChange` is.

Comment: You want to remove duplicates, right? What else?

Comment: @kinduser I only want 3 values in multi-select want to remove  duplicate values as well if user changes the value of multi-select it should also change

Comment: you are storing the selected values to the state ? sorry not clear what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: @kinduser I am storing the string of array in the database I only want the value part of multi-select. I suggest not to change the handleMultiSelectChange but to change the handleJobPreference  function.

Comment: @kinduser I want to store the values inside the job_preference state which should be a string of an array that should only have 3 values doesn't matter if the user changes the values it also changes the values. End goal is 3 string values in the job_preference state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for your needs to change slightly KcH answers.

```
const handleMultiSelectChange = (options) => {
        setMultiSelect(options);
        const values = options.map(
            (opt) => opt.value
        );
        setJobPreference([...values]);
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the `values` `onChange` of multiselect you can do as

```
  const handleMultiChange = (options) => {
    const values = options.map((opt) => opt.value);
    console.log(values);
  };
```

Comment: this won't work react-select only accepts array of objects please what ever you want to do change the job_preference function

Comment: you can do w/e you want to with the values :)